# set date format for "Sun, 17 Dec 2017 14:26:07 GMT"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Which `Postgres` date type I have to use for following date format?

```
Sun, 17 Dec 2017 14:26:07 GMT
```

I'm using `TIMESTAMPTZ` and getting this error:

```
Error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "p"
LINE 2:             VALUES ('h', 't', 't', ('p'), ('s'))
                                            ^
```

Should I convert such date before inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to *insert the datetime as a string*. Parameterize with a `datetime` object and [let the database driver handle the type conversion automatically](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "Sun, 17 Dec 2017 14:26:07 GMT"

dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO some_table (somecol) VALUES (%s)', (dt, ))
```